# Current session id in sails js

Tags: node.js, session, sails.js

I want to delete all sessions from all devices by one click in sails.js. How to get the current session id?

For example:

```
console.log(req.session.sessid) // sess:jV-M6_ZNCp-8x_jYPbSfbUilXd_T85i_
```

sails.js version 1.1.0-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All sessions are unaware of which user they belong to ***unless*** you've mapped the session in a persistent storage system like Redis/Memcached cache or MySQL, MongoDB database.

One of the many solutions I could think of is as below:

- Create a model in your sails app which can be called `SessionMapper`

  - Add three columns: userID, sessionID, and isActive (boolean).
- Now whenever a user signs in, create an entry in this model/table.
- Create a middleware through which all API requests (except `/login` and public APIs) will flow

  - This middleware will check if the current session is still active -- acting like an extra layer of authentication.

    - If the session is active, grant access / `next()`
    - if the session is invalid or `isActive` === `false`, log out the user internally and redirect to login page with some message.

To sign-out an users all active sessions, set `isActive` = `false` for `userID` = `<user-id>` in `SessionMapper` model.

**Note**: This method will increase a lot of `READ` operations on the `datasource` which is connected to `SessionMapper`. Move it to a better and efficient solution like Redis/Memcached if it hurts the primary operations.

I hope this pseudo code help you achieve your task. @tspentzas, the next time when you seek for a solution-- kindly add *whatever you've tried so far* in your question for the community to help you in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly from your question, req.session.destroy() is your answer.

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/destroy

Comment: For example, I logged in on chrome. Then I logged in on firefox. On firefox I want to click 'delete all sessions' and my session in chrome is gone.